# How to convert multiple Raster to NetCDF using ArcPy

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to convert multiple raster files to NetCDF files using an ArcPy script. When I run the below script, I get the following error message:

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    <module1>   19      
    RasterToNetCDF  C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\md.py   253     
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Catalog.
Failed to execute (RasterToNetCDF).
```

Python script:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = r"D:\2012A"

# Set local variables
inRaster = r"D:\2012A"
outNetCDFFile = r"D:\2012A/nppnetcdf.nc"
variable = "elevation"
units = "meter"
XDimension = "x"
YDimension = "y"
bandDimension = ""

# Process: RasterToNetCDF
arcpy.RasterToNetCDF_md(inRaster, outNetCDFFile, variable, units,
                        XDimension, YDimension, bandDimension)
```

Comment: I think ArcPy questions are best researched/asked at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Erica answered why you are receiving an error, though if you want to perform your conversion for each raster dataset within a directory, you'll have to first create a list of rasters within it.This can be done with something like this:

```
rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()
## other variables, as you have already defined them in your code
for raster in rasterlist:
    RastertoNetCDF_md(variables)
```

So to implement this:

```
# Set environment settings
env.workspace = r"D:\2012A"

# Set local variables
inRaster = r"D:\2012A"
outNetCDFFile = r"D:\2012A\nppnetcdf.nc"
variable = "elevation"
units = "meter"
XDimension = "x"
YDimension = "y"
bandDimension = ""
rasterlist = arcpy.ListerRasters()

# Process: RasterToNetCDF
for raster in rasterlist:
    arcpy.RasterToNetCDF_md(inRaster, outNetCDFFile, variable, units,
                    XDimension, YDimension, bandDimension)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems stand out to me.

First, your file path here `outNetCDFFile = r"D:\2012A/nppnetcdf.nc"` is invalid. Both should be backslashes `\` to get a valid path.

Second, and what is more likely causing the error -- `inRaster = r"D:\2012A"` appears to be a directory. You can't pass just a directory to the [`RasterToNetCDF_md` tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/multidimension/raster-to-netcdf.htm) -- the input parameter has to be a raster layer. Run the [`MakeRasterLayer_management` tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-raster-layer.htm) on a raster file (not on a directory!) to create a raster layer, and pass that result to `RasterToNetCDF_md`.